# Função PHP em uma página html

Tags: php, html

Porque isso não funciona:

```php
    </head>

    <body>

     <?php
        include_once '../model/Cliente.php';
        include_once '../DAO/Conexao.php';

        $conexao = new Conexao();
        $cliente = new Cliente();

        $nome = "";
        $fantasia = "";

        //chamando funcaoo
        mostrarCliente();


        /********* FUNÇÃO *****************************************
         * MOSTRANDO CLIENTE ESCOLHIDO *****************************
         ***********************************************************/
        function mostrarCliente() {
            $cliente = $conexao->selectCliente("_ID=10");

            //Se não estiver nulo, então nome recebe nome do cliente
            if (empty($cliente) == FALSE) {
                $nome = $cliente->getNome();
                $fantasia = $cliente->getFantasia();
             }
          }
       ?>
<!-- Texto e caixa - NOME CLIENTE -->
        <label>Nome Cliente</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="nome" size="80px" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" /><br  />

        <!-- Texto e caixa - NOME FANTASIA -->
        <label>Nome Fantasia</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="nome-fantasia" size="80px" value="<?php echo $fantasia; ?>" /><br />
```

Só funciona fora da função.
Será que tenho que instanciar o objeto cliente e o conexão em toda função?

Comment: Só lembrando que quando se utiliza função as variáveis externas não são as mesmas da internas, ou seja, a variável $nome e $fantasia tem valor de "" no arquivo, mas dentro da função elas são nulas, pois são variáveis diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alysson**,

As variáveis `$conexao` e `$cliente` devem ser importadas na função como global:

```
function mostrarCliente() {
        global $cliente, $conexao;
        $cliente = $conexao->selectCliente("_ID=10");
        // (...)
```

Eu transformaria a função em realmente numa função, ou seja, que recebe parâmetro e retorna valores, a quantidade de linhas seria menor e o código mais elegante e dinâmico, veja:

```
<?php
    include_once '../model/Cliente.php';
    include_once '../DAO/Conexao.php';

    $conexao = new Conexao();
    $cliente = new Cliente();

    /**
    * @param    string  Recebe nome do método
    * @return   string
    */
    function dadoCliente($get) 
    {
        $cliente = $conexao->selectCliente("_ID=10");

        //Se não estiver nulo, então nome recebe nome do cliente
        if (!empty($cliente)) 
        {
            return $cliente->$get();
        }
        return "";
      }
   ?>

    <!-- Texto e caixa - NOME CLIENTE -->
    <label>Nome Cliente</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="nome" size="80px" value="<?php echo dadoCliente('getNome'); ?>" /><br  />

    <!-- Texto e caixa - NOME FANTASIA -->
    <label>Nome Fantasia</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="nome-fantasia" size="80px" value="<?php echo dadoCliente('getFantasia'); ?>" /><br />
```

**Dica 1**

Ao invés de criar uma função sempre que for exibir dados de um cliente (ou outro objeto), você pode implementar uma classe base abstrata (`abstract`) com métodos em comum à seus objetos como `getNome`, `getEndereco` e então, criar uma classe filho (ex.: `Cliente`) que estenderá a classe base, porém, esta, com seus próprios propriedades e métodos, exemplo:

**`class.cliente.base.php`**

```
<?php
    public class ClientesBase
    {

        function __construct($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
            // restante do código para setar um cliente como query SQL, 
            // etc (que pode inclusive seguir o Query Pattern)
        }

        function getNome() { /* código que recebe o nome */ }
        function getFantasia() { /* código que recebe o a fantasia */ }
    }
?>
```

**`class.cliente.php`**

```
<?php
    public class Cliente extends ClientesBase
    {
        function getEndereco() { /* código que recebe o endereço */ }
    }
?>
```

**`exibe_cliente.php`**

```
<?php
    include_once '../model/class.cliente.php';
    include_once '../DAO/Conexao.php';

    $conexao = new Conexao();
    $cliente = new Cliente(10); // onde 10 é o ID

?>

<!-- Texto e caixa - NOME CLIENTE -->
<label>Nome Cliente</label><br />
<input type="text" name="nome" size="80px" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNome; ?>" /><br  />

<!-- Texto e caixa - NOME FANTASIA -->
<label>Nome Fantasia</label><br />
<input type="text" name="nome-fantasia" size="80px" value="<?php echo $cliente->getFantasia; ?>" /><br />
```

**Dica 2**

Sua conexão pode (na verdade, é muito recomendado) seguir o pattern `Singleton`, cujo objetivo é instanciar somente uma vez e esta estará disponível para TODA a aplicação.

**Exemplo Singleton Pattern para conexão com MySQL**

**`class.database.php`**

```
<?php
/*
* Mysql database class - somente uma conexão é permitida
*/
class Database {
    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $_host = "HOSTt";
    private $_username = "USERNAME";
    private $_password = "PASSWORd";
    private $_database = "DATABASE";

    /*
    Get an instance of the Database
    @return Instance
    */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    // Constructor
    private function __construct() {
        $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, 
            $this->_password, $this->_database);

        // Error handling
        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error("Failed to conencto to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(),
                 E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    // Magic method clone is empty to prevent duplication of connection
    private function __clone() { }

    // Get mysqli connection
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->_connection;
    }
}
?>
```

**Demo de utilização do singleton acima**

```
<?php
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection(); 
    $sql_query = "SELECT foo FROM .....";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
?>
```

No seu caso então, poderia obter a conexão:

```
<?php
    include_once '../model/Cliente.php';
    include_once '../DAO/class.database.php';

    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $conexao = $db->getConnection(); 
    $cliente = new Cliente();

    // (...)
```

Comment: Obrigado. Me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

**Respondendo sua pergunta:** você precisa informar que a variável é global, se não a função não vai encontra-la.

> Exemplo

```
function mostrarCliente() {
        global $cliente;
        $cliente = $conexao->selectCliente("_ID=10");

        //Se não estiver nulo, então nome recebe nome do cliente
        if (empty($cliente) == FALSE) {
            $nome = $cliente->getNome();
            $fantasia = $cliente->getFantasia();
        }
}
```

Comment: Não esqueça do nome e fantasia também.

Comment: Obrigado. Me ajudou muito.